# Configuring mongo DB to work with NTFS drive

Tags: permissions, ntfs, fstab, upstart, mongodb

I have 120 GB SSD Drive with two partitions (NTFS with Windows and ext4 with Ubintu) and 2TB NTFS HDD shared between Windows and Ubuntu.

I configured my HDD to be properly mounted on system boot:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
UUID=B400515500512022 /media/B400515500512022 ntfs-3g auto,users,uid=1000,gid=1001,fmask=113,dmask=002,utf8 0 0
```

I also created special group (`gid=1001`) to handle permissions and added `mongodb` user to it:

```
ntfsdrive:x:1001:leonid,mongodb
```

So, now `ntfsdrive` group have proper permissions (`rw` for files and `rwx` for directories) for the whole drive, including `mongodb` folder:

```
drwxrwxr-x 1 leonid ntfsdrive       4096 Feb  6 12:51 mongodb
```

But mongodb still refuses to run on this drive:

```
Wed Feb  6 12:51:31 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=7480 port=27017 dbpath=/media/B400515500512022/mongodb 64-bit host=ubuntu
Wed Feb  6 12:51:31 [initandlisten] db version v2.2.3, pdfile version 4.5
Wed Feb  6 12:51:31 [initandlisten] git version: f570771a5d8a3846eb7586eaffcf4c2f4a96bf08
Wed Feb  6 12:51:31 [initandlisten] build info: Linux ip-10-2-29-40 2.6.21.7-2.ec2.v1.2.fc8xen #1 SMP Fri Nov 20 17:48:28 EST 2009 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
Wed Feb  6 12:51:31 [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongodb.conf", dbpath: "/media/B400515500512022/mongodb", logappend: "true", logpath: "/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log" }
Wed Feb  6 12:51:31 [initandlisten] journal dir=/media/B400515500512022/mongodb/journal
Wed Feb  6 12:51:31 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
Wed Feb  6 12:51:31 [initandlisten] info preallocateIsFaster couldn't run due to: couldn't open file /media/B400515500512022/mongodb/journal/tempLatencyTest for writing errno:1 Operation not permitted; returning false
Wed Feb  6 12:51:31 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 13516 couldn't open file /media/B400515500512022/mongodb/journal/j._0 for writing errno:1 Operation not permitted, terminating
Wed Feb  6 12:51:31 dbexit: 
Wed Feb  6 12:51:31 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Wed Feb  6 12:51:31 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Wed Feb  6 12:51:31 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Wed Feb  6 12:51:31 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Wed Feb  6 12:51:31 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
Wed Feb  6 12:51:31 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
Wed Feb  6 12:51:31 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
Wed Feb  6 12:51:31 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
Wed Feb  6 12:51:31 [initandlisten] journalCleanup...
Wed Feb  6 12:51:31 [initandlisten] removeJournalFiles
Wed Feb  6 12:51:31 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
Wed Feb  6 12:51:31 dbexit: really exiting now
```

I have no problems running mongodb with the same configuration (including `mongodb` folder permissions) on my `ext4` drive.

Is there a way to solve this problem, or my only option is to add `ext4` partition to my HDD drive?

Comment: I suggest that you first confirm that the mongodb user really does have write permissions to your NTFS partition. Try running `sudo -u mongodb touch /media/B400515500512022/mongodb/testfile`. If that fails it is a simple permissions issue rather than a fault with MongoDB, which will simplify troubleshooting.

Comment: `testfile` was created successfully. I also created a directory. So, permissions is ok.

Comment: But its a permission issue all the same, because `sudo -u mongodb mongod --dbpath /media/B400515500512022/mongodbq` fails while `mongodb mongod --dbpath /media/B400515500512022/mongodb` starts mongodb successfully.

Comment: Was "mongodbq" a typo? Have you run mongod as your own user, or as root at any point? Maybe check the ownership of all files and directories in /media/B400515500512022/mongodb? You could also try adding `-g ntfsdrive` to your sudo command.

Comment: Yes, it was a typo. As for the ownership, NTFS can't handle permissions, so it's the same for the whole drive (`leonid ntfsdrive`). Even if `mongodb` user creates a file the owner is still me and `ntfsdrive` group. Adding `-g ntfsdrive` seems reasonable, but it fails with the same error. I believe that changing the owner of the whole drive to `mongodb` may help. Though I don't want to do it, I should test it anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having replicated this myself, it appears that using the mount options you specify allows the `mongodb` user to write to the NTFS volume, but there is something specific that MongoDB is trying to do with the files that is not permitted by these options; perhaps it cannot set the umask or ownership on its files exactly how it wants to.

The solution is to use the `permissions` option when mounting the NTFS volume rather than specifying the owner explicitly. See the [ntfs-3g](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/ntfs-3g.8.html) man page for further details.

So `/etc/fstab` would look like this:

```
UUID=B400515500512022 /media/B400515500512022 ntfs-3g defaults,locale=en_US.UTF-8,permissions 0 0
```

On a fresh NTFS volume mounted at `/media/B400515500512022`, you can then run:

```
sudo mkdir /media/B400515500512022/mongodb
sudo chown mongodb:mongodb /media/B400515500512022/mongodb
```

before running:

```
sudo -u mongodb mongod --dbpath /media/B400515500512022/mongodb
```

You may wish to check that this does not cause problems when accessing the files from Windows.

Comment: Is it possible to set a default owner for the files on the drive? It looks like I can't use `uid` and `gid` options along with `permissions` option and by default its `root:root`.

Comment: Of course, I can run `sudo chown -R leonid:leonid /media/B400515500512022`, but what if I'll add some new files from my Windows afterward?

Comment: Typically, if multiple users are to own files on a volume, you would leave the root directory owned by root and then create subdirectories that you can change the ownership of to control access. But only you can decide how important security is here. The [ntfs-3g manual](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-manual/) describes how to set up a user mapping file between your Linux and Windows user accounts.

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary solution I reconfigured `mongodb` upstart script. I configured it to run `mongodb` using my own user instead of `mongodb` user.

To do so I changed the following line in the `/etc/init/mongodb.conf` file:

```
if [ "x$ENABLE_MONGODB" = "xyes" ]; then exec start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --chuid mongodb --exec  /usr/bin/mongod -- --config /etc/mongodb.conf; fi
```

Both `--chuid mongodb:ntfsdrive` and `--chuid leonid` options resulted in the same error, so I completely removed `--chuid` option from it:

```
if [ "x$ENABLE_MONGODB" = "xyes" ]; then exec start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --exec  /usr/bin/mongod -- --config /etc/mongodb.conf; fi
```

Running `mongodb` using my own user isn't a good solution, so I  think I'll partition my HDD drive to prevent similar problems.